# Is it possible to generate entity classes and create tables from liquibase scripts?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

I have the database changelog file. Now I need to generate entity classes and tables too. I use intellij with JPA buddy plugin. I also checked something like reverse engineering but no success. I use spring boot with postgres and liquibase. I just added the liquibase xml files. I have declared all the database configuration in my application.yml file but when i start server, none of the scripts execute. I am not sure what I am missing

pom entry :

```
<!--liquibase-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

application-env.yml

```
datasource:
platform: postgres
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/localdb
username: postgres
password: postgres
driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

application.yml

```
liquibase:
change-log: classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
```

I have placed the xml files in these path .During server startup I dont get any errors and the liquibase xml files also dont get executed.
enter code here

Comment: Can you add the contents of your liquibase.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase generally doesn't do anything with your entity files. It is all about comparing the changesets in your changelog file with what is stored in the database's databasechangelog table and running whatever database changes haven't ran.

There is the [Liquibase hibernate extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate) which will allow you to ***generate*** changesets from your entity metadata, but that is something you do as a separate process:

1. Modify your entity classes
2. Run liquibase diff-changelog
3. Make sure the added changesets match what you expect and modify them as needed

Going the other way (from a database structure to entity objects) would need something like JPABuddy and would be more like:

1. Add new changeSets your changelog file
2. Run liquibase update
3. Use JPABuddy to update the entity objects from the new database structure

Either approach can work, but you need one side or the other to generate from.

BUT: it looks like the root of your problem is that the changesets you do have in db/changelog/changelog-master.xml is not running?

Adding the dependency like you have should be all that is needed to enable Liquibase update on startup with spring boot.

- Are there any errors in the log on startup? Perhaps it failed running liquibase but continued booting anyway?
- Are you using an includeAll in db/changelog/changelog-master.xml? If the directory you point to does not exist or is mis-entered, by default liquibase will simply continue on
- Is the `<dependency>` in a dependencyManagement section not dependencies?